# Mixed mode assembly is built against version 'v2.0.50727' ... error on native C++ / Visual C++ / C# projects

Tags: c#, c++, .net, wrapper, compatibility

I am trying to instantiate a C# class in a native C++ .exe project using a Visual C++ wrapper.

The C# project targets .Net 3.5 framework, and this cannot be changed. 
Both C++ and Visual C++ projects are build using the v100 compiler.

But I still get the `Mixed mode assembly is built against version 'v2.0.50727' of the runtime and cannot be loaded in the 4.0 runtime without additional configuration information`.

I have also tried to add

```
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v3.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

to the `<PropertyGroup Label="Globals">` elements of the .vcxproj files of the C++ projects, but still the error.

If somebody has a an idea, he/she will be welcomed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly question of myself, simple answer :

*Use **v90** compiler to target .Net 3.5*